# Validate Firebase access token?

Tags: firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, jwt

When I generate a token using `createCustomToken` from [Firebase admin sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), how can I verify that is the valid token without using the SDK again?

I assumed its a valid OAuth token but I can not find the signing key and therefore check the integrity. I use Firebase Auth for storing the token and the admin sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Tokens created with the Firebase admin SDK are signed using a service account. In the default setting the service account email has the form `firebase-adminsdk-bh96s@<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

Under `https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/<service account email>` you will find the corresponding public keys.

See also https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

Answer (score -1):

Firebase ID tokens are JWTs (JSON Web Tokens) and can be verified either with the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk), or [with any other JWT parsing library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library).

Comment: Thanks, I so far use the custom token and thought about moving to id tokens ... but I so far got the impression they are for the signup and not access requests. Or are they the same and do I check it with this https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com key as well?